# CodeIgniter params are not passing to library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ok I'm trying to pass parameteres to the constructor of my library I created to extend the CI_Form_validation class.
Anyway, here is what I'm passing from my model:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Form_validation', array('config' => '', 'post' => $this->input->post()));
```

Then here is the MY_Form_validation library:

```
private $post;

    public function __construct($params) {
        parent::__construct($params['config']);
        $this->post = $params['post'];
    }
```

But it's saying I'm not passing anything in. Here are the error messages:

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for MY_Form_validation::__construct(), called in H:\WD SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source\DStable\stable\core\Loader.php on line 1099 and defined
Message: Undefined variable: params
```

EDIT
On request, the whole class:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    private $post;

    public function __construct($params) {
        parent::__construct($params['config']);
        $this->post = $params['post'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you loading the form_validation library anywhere else? Specifically in the autoloader?

Comment: Wait what? If you load classes in the autoloader, does it load everywhere? I'm not loading it anywhere. Actually, I'm loading it in the register.php controller! Does that matter??

Comment: Can you post your class declaration for your my_form_validation?

Comment: What do you mean the declaration? Here let me just I guess post the beginning and everything unless that's what the declaration is :P

Comment: Try removing "MY_" from the load->library. CI automatically looks for a "MY_" version of a library before loading

Comment: In the original `form_validation` library, you will find that `rules`, or in your case `params` is actually optional, where as your override is not. Change `function __construct($params)` to `function __constructor($params = array())`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just pass an empty array instead of an empty string as the first parameter to your constructor, which is sent to the parent:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Form_validation', array('config' => array(), 'post' => $this->input->post()));
```

The CI Form Validation library actually initializes the config argument as such, this is the constructor from `system/libraries/Form_validation.php`:

```
public function __construct($rules = array())
```